# How do I know if an app is safe to use?

Tags: installation, apt, security, viruses

Is there any reliable way to know if something that you install is safe? There are virus scanners like clamtk, but those only seem to focus on Windows files. Should I be concerned about viruses / rootkits in something I might apt-get install? How can I check?

Comment: Check out the related questions on the right hand side of the page. Variations of this question can be found there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything you install via *apt-get* or the *Software Center* from the original sources is safe to use, as it is tested and verified by a lot of people, including the Ubuntu team.

Comment: does this include regular apt?

Comment: Yes. `apt` uses the same sources as `apt-get` - just be careful when adding custom repositories as their content might not be tested/reviewed as carefully.